# Cabeçalho da página em detalhes de seção no Crystal Reports

Tags: visual-studio-2013, crystal-reports, relatório

Bom dia à todos!

Criei um relatório de comissões com Crystal Reports no Visual Studio com filtro de datas. Todo mês é enviado aos vendedores individualmente suas comissões no período. Para abrir os detalhes do vendedor, basta clicar duas vezes em cima do seu grupo e é aberto isoladamente as vendas do mesmo. Porém, gostaria que fosse mantido o cabeçalho do relatório, onde estão informações de período, data de impressão e nome da empresa. Alguém sabe como fazer?

Obrigado!

Comment: pode configurar para que apareça um vendedor por pagina também acho que ficaria mais profissional, 1 vendedor por pagina, sairia o cabeçalho para cada e poderia adicionar o tipo de relatório Analítico e Sintético deixar por opção do usuário seria uma outra opção apenas uma dica abraço.

Answer (score 3):

```
Crystal Reports > Report > Report Options... > Mostrar todos os cabeçalhos na pesquisa detalhada
```

Isso resolve meu problema.
Fica a dica para quem utiliza o Crystal!